# Error connected to Blockchain

Tags: nethereum

Most of the Nethereum samples provide the same simple way to connect:

```
Using Nethereum.Web3;

var web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io");
```

However this results in the following error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'JsonRpcSharp.Client.IClient'

When I add `Using Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client;`

```
var client = new RpcClient(new Uri("https:mainnet.infura.io"));
```

I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'RpcClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, can you share the entire code you are trying to run? I tested their example in their docs, and it works fine with that syntax. Did you install everything following the steps?

http://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

so based on the code you shared in the comments, you are trying to connect to a node through the `geth.icp` file. Unfortunately, I don't have access to one and cannot test my code properly, but this is what I see in your code:

There are multiple definitions of the same variable "var web3", which isn't allowed in C#. Every variable name needs to be unique within a scope.

Also, it looks like the code is using two different methods to create a Web3 instance, which could lead to some unexpected behavior. Both `ClientFactory.GetClient()` and new `Nethereum.JsonRpc.IpcClient.IpcClient(new Uri("localhost:8545"), Http, null)` is being used, which might not be the best way to create a Web3 instance.

Try this to connect using `geth.icp`

```cs
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Contracts;

namespace BlazorApp.Pages
{
    public partial class BlazorAppDapp : ComponentBase
    {
        private void ConnectToBlockchain(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var web3 = new Web3(new Nethereum.JsonRpc.IpcClient.IpcClient("./geth.ipc"));
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is tested and works after properly installing the library to connect using HTTP.

```cs
// Nethereum.Web3 docs: http://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/getting-started/
using Nethereum.Web3;

namespace NethereumSample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Web3? web3;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeWeb3();
            GetAccountBalance().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            
            GetLatestBlock().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void InitializeWeb3()
        {
            web3 = new Web3("YOUR_ETHEREUM_ENDPOINT");
        }

        private static async Task GetAccountBalance()
        {
            var balance = await web3!.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync("0x44dd3f13838eb39C91e6514d18B6a98D854dEe79");
            Console.WriteLine($"Balance in Wei: {balance.Value}");

            var etherAmount = Web3.Convert.FromWei(balance.Value);
            Console.WriteLine($"Balance in Ether: {etherAmount}");
        }

        private static async Task GetLatestBlock()
        {
            var block = await web3!.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockNumber.SendRequestAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Latest block: {block}");
        }
    }
}
```

You can reference the [Nethereum.Web3 docs](http://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/getting-started/) to make sure the library is properly installed.

Comment: With 'var web3 = new Web3(new Nethereum.JsonRpc.IpcClient.IpcClient("./geth.ipc"));'  I get the error 'The type name 'IpcClient' does not exist in the type 'IpcClient'

Comment: I noticed that the Nethereum sample utilizes a console application, which I did get to work. However it does not work in a C# Blazor partial class . I found a Blazor sample that I am going to try.